# Redux store trigger a infinity rerender

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-redux

I have this service class to get the data from backend. I'm making a get request to get some data in the getProjects method, i'm using axios:

```
export default class MissionService {

keycloak: KeycloakInstance
dispatch: AppDispatch
store

constructor(keycloak: KeycloakInstance){

this.store = useAppSelector((store) => store.xproj)
this.dispatch = useAppDispatch();
this.keycloak = keycloak;

}

async getProjects(){

if (!this.keycloak.token) return;

    backendAPI.defaults.headers.common[
      'Authorization'
    ] = `Bearer ${this.keycloak.token}`;


    await backendAPI
    .get('/mission/user')
    .then(({ data }) => {
      this.dispatch(setProjectList(data))
    })
    .catch((error) => errorNotification(error.response.data.message));
    
 }
```

After the data is recieve, it's dispatch the data to the store. In my store i'm only saving the data, nothing more:

```
setProjectList: (state, action: PayloadAction<XProjProject[]>) => {

    state.projectsList = action.payload

},
```

I want to get this data when a specific component open:

```
const {

projectsList

} = useAppSelector((state) => state.xproj);

useEffect(() => { 

   missionService.getProjects()

}, [projectsList]);
```

But if i put the "projectList" inside the useEffect brackets, it's trigger a infinite rerender. Everytime is making a request to the backend. I have to remove the "projectsList" from the brackets, but it's not what i want because every time i create a new project, i want to update the components that using the "projectList" state.

Could anyone help with this, please? Thanks for any help.

Comment: How is this code not complaining about calling the `useAppSelector` and `useAppDispatch` hooks outside a React Function component and/or custom React hook? This is surely breaking the [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Comment: For whatever reason, if i put this inside the getProjects method, it's trigger the react hook error. So, i did like this.

Comment: Yeah, `getProjects` isn't a React component or custom hook either. I'm curious as to how `MissionService` is being used that *doesn't* trigger the React warning for you and yet still somehow works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the `projectsList` in the brackets means that the `useEffect` will run again every time `projectsList` changes. Because the effect updates `projectsList`, running the effect will cause it to run again. `projectsList` should not be in those brackets.

You say that you want `projectsList` updated whenever you create a new project. I suggest doing that: update `projectsList` in a separate call when you do something like creating a new project.